# Proving that a $T_{1\frac{1}{3}}$-space is $T_1$-space

Tags: general-topology

Call a space $T_{1\frac{1}{3}}$ if every sequence in it has at most one limit.  A $T_1$ space is a space in which for two distinct points $a$ and $b$, there are open sets $U$ and $V$ for which $a$ belongs to $U$ but $b$ does not, and $b$ belongs to $V$ but $a$ does not.

To show that a $T_{1\frac{1}{3}}$-space is $T_1$, we will prove the contrapositive.  Suppose $X$ is a space that is not $T_1$.  Then for some pair of points $x,y \in X$ either (i) there are no open sets containing $x,y$, (ii) there is an open set containing (say) $x$ but not $y$, or (iii) every open set containing $x$ also contains $y$ (for, if an open set containing $x$ does not contain $y$ then either the situation would fall under (ii) or $y$ would be contained in an open set not containing $x$, but this would contradict our assumption that $X$ is not $T_1$).

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $X$.  In case (i), it is vacuously true that there is a $N_x$ and $N_y$ for which $\forall n \ge N_x$ or $\forall n \ge N_y$, $x_n$ is in all open sets containing $x$ or $y$, respectively, so both $x$ and $y$ are limits of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$.
In case (ii), suppose $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x$.  Then it also converges vacuously to $y$.
In case (iii), if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x$, there is an $N_x$ such that $\forall n \ge N_x$, $x_n$ is in every open set containing $x$, and therefore every open set containing $y$, and so $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $y$ as well.  In all these cases, $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to two limits, and so $X$ cannot be a $T_{1\frac{1}{3}}$-space.  It follows that if $X$ is $T_{1\frac{1}{3}}$, it must be $T_1$.

Is this proof valid, and if so is there a way to simplify it?  I'm not great at coming up with creative, non-brute-force proofs.  Thanks, the help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If every open set around $a$ contains $b$, then $\{b,b,b,b,\cdots\}$ converges to both $a$ and $b$. If every open set around $b$ contains $a$, then $\{a,a,a,a,\cdots\}$ converges to both $a$ and $b$. Both of these are impossible since our space is $T_{1 \frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: May I have a little more?

Comment: Done. Please let me know if it requires further clarification.

Comment: Note that your second paragraph alone essentially proves the result by contrapositive.  (If $X$ is not $\text{T}_1$ then there are points $a,b$ such that every open neighbourhood of $a$ contains $b$, _etc._)

Comment: Oh, rightly noted. I did suspect something was unnecessary..

Comment: @Isaac: I understand what you're saying, but unfortunately I don't see how it proves the result.  Aren't there are other cases to consider?  And is this a simplification or a correction of my proof?

Comment: What other cases are there to consider? We have here two sequences, and they only have at most one limit if $b$ contains an open set without $a$, and vice versa. Since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, the proof is complete.

Comment: @Isaac: ok, I see it now.  Thanks.