# Showing that a $T_{1\frac{2}{3}}$-space is a $T_{1\frac{1}{3}}$-space

Tags: general-topology

Here's part two (sort of) to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286270/proving-that-a-t-1-frac13-space-is-t-1-space) question.

I am trying to show that every $T_{1\frac{2}{3}}$-space is a $T_{1\frac{1}{3}}$-space, where a space is $T_{1\frac{2}{3}}$ if each compact set is closed, and a space is $T_{1\frac{1}{3}}$ if each sequence has at most one limit.

Unfortunately, after playing around with various properties of compact spaces, closed spaces, the definition of a convergent sequence, etc., I've really gotten nowhere.

Can someone give me a hint as to how to go about this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $p$ and to $q$, and consider the compact set $K=\{p\}\cup\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; if $q\ne p$, is $K$ closed?

Comment: I definitely understand the idea, but why is $K$ compact?

Comment: @Alex: Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $K$. There must be some $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $p\in U_0$. And then there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in U_0$ for all $n\ge m$, so ... ?

Comment: So there are only finitely many $x_n$ not in $U_0$, and since every finite set is compact, then so is $K$. (I try to tag you and it disappears when I post the comment.)

Comment: @Alex: You’ve got it. (Comments on an answer automatically ping the author of the answer; that’s why you can’t add the ping tag.)

Comment: Good.  And I wasn't aware of that, thanks.

Comment: @Alex: You’re welcome.